# Is it possible to control a Mac Mini with VNC and a Magic Trackpad simultaneously?

Tags: mac, vnc, touchpad, magic-trackpad

Is it possible to remote control a Mac Mini from another computer through VNC (screen and keyboard sharing), but using the Magic Trackpad connected to the Mac Mini to control the mouse pointer and touch gestures?

Comment: just controlling the mouse and gestures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, **yes**. No problem with that.

The only issues that might arise:

- If the controlling PC moves the mouse, VNC will immediately set the mouse pointer to the location on the controlling PC. Therefore, if you move the mouse on the Mac, and somebody moves the mouse on the PC, the PC takes precedence.
- Also, if you move the mouse on the Mac, the controlling PC will **not** see these mouse movements. Not even when you click somewhere or enter text.
- If you type on the controlling PC, then the mouse pointer might disappear on the Mac's screen.

Comment: no mac screen. is the magic trackpad tracked also on controlling pc screen?

Comment: @P5music See my updated answer. Does not seem to work, with VNC, at least.